# looking for a node.js scheduler that wont start if the job is still running

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling, job-scheduling

I'm looking for a schedular/ cron for nodejs.
But I need an important feature- if the jobs did not finish (when the time for it to start again arrived), I want it to not start/ delay the schedule.
For example, I need to run a job every 5 minutes. The job started at 8:00, but finished only at 8:06. so I want the job of 8:05 to either wait until 8:06, or not to start at all, and wait for the next cycle at 8:10.
Is there a package that does that? If not, what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package. It allows you to start/stop the cronjob manually. Which means you can call these functions when your cronjob is finished.

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
let job;

// The function you are running
const someFunction = () => {
    job.stop();

    doSomething(() => {
        // When you are done
        job.start();
    })
};

// Create new cronjob
job = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '00 00 1 * * *',
    onTick: someFunction,
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});

// Auto start your cronjob
job.start();
```

Comment: Tnanks! After looking at your solution I did something a bit different- at the end of the function, I call a timeout to this date plus 5 minutes. This works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it by yourself:

```
// The job has to have a method to inform about completion
function myJob(input, callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 10 * 60 * 1000); // It will complete in 10 minutes
}

// Scheduler
let jobIsRunning = false;
function scheduler() {
  // Do nothing if job is still running
  if (jobIsRunning) {
    return;
  }

  // Mark the job as running
  jobIsRunning = true;
  myJob('some input', () => {
    // Mark the job as completed
    jobIsRunning = false;
  });
}

setInterval(scheduler, 5 * 60 * 1000); // Run scheduler every 5 minutes
```